# Doing Something On Type In EditText

Tags: java, android

In my app I am trying to check if an ArrayList contains what is typed in the EditText every time someone types in it.
Here is where I attempt that:

```
 public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.etssid:
            if(wifiSSID.contains(etSSID.getText())){
                etPASS.setText(wifiSSID.indexOf(etSSID.getText()));
        }

        }
        return false;
    }
```

The issues is it never gets to inside the if. If I remove the if this it works:

```
 switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.etssid:
            etPASS.setText("It Works"); 
        }
```

Now I have dumbed down the .contains. I made an ArrayList at the top of my class and added an element. There would be no interference and it doesnt work. What can I do to check if the text equals something in the arraylist everytime someone types a letter?

Comment: Can't you just check when the EditText no longer equals null? (etSSID != null)

Comment: No because I neeed the exact text in it to see if it is in an Array

Comment: Yeah but once you know it isn't null, you can then do etSSID.getText()?

Answer (score 1):

I think contains doesnt works here.

Instead you have to use wifiSSID.contentequals or wifiSSID.equals

you may also need to change this in if loop condition
etSSID.getText().tostring()

Answer (score 0):

use textwacher method

editext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

```
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
                {

                }

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
                {
                   // Dome something here
                   if(wifiSSID.contains(etSSID.getText())){
                   etPASS.setText(wifiSSID.indexOf(etSSID.getText()));

                }

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
                {

                }
        });
```

This textwatcher method rns everytime you press any key.,.,ontextchanged method is called everytime and you can check for any condition in it. Check tutorials for more insight in textwatcher